# Double is not a nullable type

Tags: c#, linq

I am doing this with LINQ:

```
        // let use Linq
        var DateMarket = from p in Orders_From_CRD.AsEnumerable()
                         where p.Field<Double>("Fill_ID") != null
                         select OrderTable.Rows.Add(p.Field<DateTime>("trade_date"), p.Field<string>("ticker"),
                         p.Field<Double>("EXEC_QTY"), p.Field<Double>("EXEC_PRICE"));

        TradeTable = DateMarket.CopyToDataTable();
```

But I have an error telling me

```
Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Double'. Please use a nullable type.
```

Do you know how to cast nullable type in this case ?

I tried `<Double?>` and I got `'Specified cast is not valid.'`

Comment: Have you checked the type of the column in the database table?  "Specified cast is not valid" would be the error if you try to cast a non-double value to `double?`.  The type could be IEEE single, or decimal, or some integer type.

Comment: `<Double?> `was the solution, i did not work because I was using the wrong cast. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
p.Field<Double?>
```

`T?` is shorthand for `Nullable<T>`, a wrapper for a value type that allows null values.

Comment: I tried that and i got 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Answer (score 4):

Use the type :

```
Double?
```

when you need a nullable double

Answer (score 3):

by default, double can't be assigned null values. The solution to this problem is to use a nullable type : Double?

try this:

```
        var DateMarket = from p in Orders_From_CRD.AsEnumerable()
                     where p.Field<Double?>("Fill_ID") != null
                     select OrderTable.Rows.Add(p.Field<DateTime>("trade_date"), p.Field<string>("ticker"),
                     p.Field<Double?>("EXEC_QTY"), p.Field<Double?>("EXEC_PRICE"));

    TradeTable = DateMarket.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: `Fill_ID` is less likely to be `NULL` than, say, `EXEC_PRICE` (e.g. on an unfilled fill).

Comment: There is a second double in there that I assume may need the same treatment...